# Transform username in Azure AD B2C authentication

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I would like to create logical tenants of users with B2C by appending an account number to their username. So the user might conceive of their username as Bob, but I would be appending their account number to it (e.g. Bob1234). Are there any known hooks to transform the username entered by the user before authenticating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a custom policy. https://aka.ms/ief

Before writing, reading and verifying credentials, use a claims transform to append the account number to the username:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#formatstringmultipleclaims

Comment: can you guys clarify how this working exactly.
So the user enters from the login screen "someusername" and "password", now internally before authentication takes place the username is concatenated with account number and the new username used is internally for authentication from AD. Do I understand correctly? if yes, at which point the entered username is intercepted, new claim is created as username-account and used for login?  thank you