# B2C modifying entered from B2C login username before loging-in to AD

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using Azure AD B2C Local Accounts Sign-in with custom policies.
Is there a way to intercept the username entered before validation, modify it and then continue with validation with the modified name?

I am using a single tenant for multiple organizations and by concatenating organization with username i want to create a uniqueness to resolve more then 1 user from 2+ organizations  having the same username.

looking at
[Transform username in Azure AD B2C authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69133525/transform-username-in-azure-ad-b2c-authentication)
did not help, am I missing something?

Thank you